# Pyspark can't write spark df into pandas df in spark shell

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I've created pyspark yarn process, with 6 cores and 60 GB of memory to load data from csv's. Now when I've loaded, I need to transform it to pandas dataframe. 
I've tried with `df.toPandas()` and the process is started, but after every few minutes, stage start all over again (like refresh from zero) This is what I have in a moment of typing this question.

```
[Stage : 10 > ----------------                       (0 + 836) / 11830]
```

But in a few moments it's going to refresh number where 836 is now to 0 and give me some bunch of errors, like the process stopped due to stage error. 
Do you maybe know what causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas), the `df.ToPandas()` is meant to be used with small datasets.

> Note This method should only be used if the resulting Pandas’s
>   DataFrame is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the
>   driver’s memory.